# How to leave first iteration elements?

Tags: python

```
with open(args[0]) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                pass
```

How to leave first iteration elements in my example?

Example data:

```
000, 000, 000,
666, 444, 555,
111, 111, 111,
```

I need to leave `000, 000, 000,`

Comment: You can just call `.next()` outside the for loop: `reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') reader.next() for row in reader: doSomething`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `next` to skip a row:

```
with open(args[0]) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    next(reader, None)  # Read and skip first line
    for row in reader:
        pass
```

Be careful to give the second argument to `next`, which is what it returns if the iterator is already empty (in case of empty file), even though you don't care about it. Otherwise `StopIteration` will be raised, which can lead to really unexpected behaviour if you happen to call the function this is in from inside a generator expression somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `next()` outside the for loop to skip the line

```
with open(args[0]) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        doSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
for i in range(1, len(reader)):
    row = reader[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your files are not extremely large. If that assumption is wrong, forget about this solution. If it is right, the best solution, from the semantic point of view, in my opinion is:

```
with open(args[0]) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    rows = list(reader)

for r in rows[1:]:
    do_stuff_with_row(r)
```

This separates your task in two steps:

- reading the file, building the list of rows
- iterating through a sub-set of the rows

It is *not* the most memory-efficient solution, but in most application scenarios this does not matter at all. If memory-efficiency is of interest to you, use a `next()`-based solution. Note that this approach here can be improved using `itertools`, especially `itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])`.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
with open(args[0]) as f:
        index = 0
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            index++
            if(index=1):
                pass
            do somthing
```

Comment: You're missing something, the value of `index` never changes.

Comment: Neither `index++` nor `if(index=1):` are valid Python syntax.